# How to instantiate and Display a ViewModel from another view model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I'm new to MVVM, I followed [josh smith article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and I am struggling developing my first attempt. In my case I have a main window that has a main view model:

```
var vm = new MainVM();
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
window.DataContext = vm;
```

I have two viewmodels `ItemSuppliersViewModel`, `SuppliersViewModel` binded to two views `ItemSuppliers`, `SuppliersView` using `datatemplate` in the mainwindow `resourcedictionary` as follows:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:ItemSuppliersViewModel}">
    <VV:ItemSuppliersView/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:SuppliersViewModel}">
    <VV:SuppliersView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

In the main window I have a listbox displaying a list of items Binded to:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding     SelectedItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Item_Name" />
```

the `AllItems` is a public property exposed by the Main view model:

```
public IList<Item> AllItems { get { return (IList<Item>)_itemsRepository.FindAll(DetachedCriteria.For<Item>()); } }
```

When the user select an item from the list box a list of some data related to this item is displayed represented by the `ItemSuppliers` View model and `ItemSuppliersView` and displayed into a grid using `itemscontrol`:

```
<Grid Margin="246,132,93,94">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSuppliersVM}" Margin="4"/>
    </Grid>
```

The `ItemSuppliersVM` is exposed in the main view model as following:

```
ItemSuppliersViewModel itemSuppliersVM;
public ItemSuppliersViewModel ItemSuppliersVM
    {
        get
        {
            return _itemSuppliersVM;
        }
        set
        {
            _itemSuppliersVM = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ItemSuppliersVM");
        }
    }
```

Here is the selecteditem property that is binded to the listbox selected item:

```
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            ShowItemSuppliers();
        }
    }
```

the `showItemSuppliers` that creates the itemsuppliers view model:

```
void ShowItemSuppliers()
    {         
        _itemSuppliersVM = new ItemSuppliersViewModel(_itemsRepository, _selectedItem, new DateTime(2011, 03, 01), new DateTime(2011, 03, 30));
    }
```

The problem is that when selecting any item in the list box nothing happened, however the `itemsrepository` is tested and works fine, when I but a break point all bindings are working and it walks through the `selecteditem` property and then the `showitemsuppliers()` method.

**I think the problem is in this method, so what's wrong and is this method is the right way to instantiate the `ItemSuppliersViewModel` in the mainwindow view model?**

Comment: you have a typo in <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:SuppiersViewModel}">

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the field directly, and aren't raising the `PropertyChanged` event. Without raising that event, the binding engine won't know that your property has changed. If you change

```
_itemSuppliersVM = new ItemSuppliersViewModel(_itemsRepository, _selectedItem, new DateTime(2011, 03, 01), new DateTime(2011, 03, 30));
```

to

```
ItemSuppliersVM = new ItemSuppliersViewModel(_itemsRepository, _selectedItem, new DateTime(2011, 03, 01), new DateTime(2011, 03, 30));
```

your binding should work.